# Is there any other open web fonts API like Google fonts?

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

We are using google fonts API https://developers.google.com/fonts/?csw=1 to provide possibility for users to change custom font. Can you suggest other open API like google fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try adobe, they have a better typographic pedigree, imho, than google, and it's free (up to a point): [adobe](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/05/16/adobe-edge-web-fonts-a-google-web-fonts-alternative/)

Answer (score 2):

yes there is other web font APIs

you can use those APIs
https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/index 
http://www.fonts.com/browse
https://typekit.com  - not free
https://www.myfonts.com/info/webfonts/  - not free
http://www.webink.com/   - not free
http://www.fontspring.com/  - not free
http://fontdeck.com/  - not free